# Significance of rank of frechet derivative in definition of manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

In studying manifolds, the stipulation that the derivative be full rank is confusing to me on an intuitive level. Can anyone please explain how I should think about this intuitively? What does it mean for the derivative to be full rank? What would it mean for the derivative to not be full rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what scenario did you encounter this condition? I think the most famous place you need the full rank assumption for the inverse function theorem in $\mathbb R^n$. Here, full rank is equivalent to the Jacobian (which is an $n \times n$ matrix) having non-zero determinant. This is a generalization of the derivative from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ not being zero, this is usually synonymous to a function being one to one on connected sets (I.e. Intervals). Can you see how this is just a generalized analogy?